# Elasticsearch Jest update a whole document

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jest

I have an elasticsearch server which i'm accessing via a java server using the Jest client and i was looking for the best way to update multiple fields of a document each time.

I have looked to the documentation  so far, and i have found that there are two way for doing it :

1. [Partial update via a script](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/partial-updates.html) : i don't think it is suitable for multiple field update (because i don't know the modified fields).
2. [Whole document update](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/master/update-doc.html): via re-indexing the whole document.

My question is how could i update the whole document knowing that Jest provide only update via a script?

Is it the best way to delete a document and indexing the updated version?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Already answered this in the github issue you also opened but again:

You should use the second way you linked (Whole document update) and there is no special API for it, it's just a regular index request. So you can do it simply by sending your `Index` request against the `id` of the document you want to update.

For example assuming you have below document already indexed in Elasticsearch within index `people`, type `food`, id `9`:

```
{"user": "kramer", "fav_food": "jello"}
```

Then you would do:

```
String source = "{\"user\": \"kramer\", \"fav_food\": \"pizza\"}";
JestResult result = client.execute(
            new Index.Builder(source)
                    .index("people")
                    .type("food")
                    .id(9)
                    .build()
    );
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was wondering if could pass an Object as a source like when Indexing ?

Comment: Yes you can; `Builder` takes any object as long as Gson can serialize it.